# Rewriting URL that has 2 question marks in it using Rewriter in Config

Tags: .net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, config

I can't use friendly URLs in my DotNetNuke site and a module that I want to use requires it.  The problem is when they post to the 2nd part of the module process they tack on a "?ctlname=Step2" and then "?ctlname=Step3" for the next step.  So...

the Url ends up being something like this:

default.aspx?tab=123**?**ctlname=Step2

I'm trying to solve this by rewriting the URL.  This seems like it should work but doesn't.

```
<RewriterRule>
  <LookFor>.*/Default.aspx\?tabid=123(\?ctlname=.*)$</LookFor>
  <SendTo>~/Default.aspx?tabid=123&amp;ctlname=$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't use multiple question marks in URLs, you should delimit different parameters with an ampersand, e.g. `default.aspx?tab=123&ctlname=Step2`

Comment: No kidding.  If we were the ones writing the URL we wouldn't.  We have to handle the code the module is spitting out.  We didn't write the module. :)

Comment: Ugh.  That's all I have to say about the problem. Good luck! :)

Comment: Totally agree!  I have since asked for the source code.. we'll see.  thx for the help at any rate.

Comment: Time to ditch that module or developer cause they don't know what they are doing....

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I used it but [Snapsis Pageblaster](http://www.snapsis.com/DotNetNuke-Performance-Caching-Compression-Optimization.aspx) may be able to help.
It essentially caches, optimizes your performance but it has another cool feature that can search/replace content before it's send to the client browser. So you can do rewrite rules with it and might be able to clean up those URLs if you can't get the source code.

If they are using ? marks for all URL parameters then I imagine that source code is going to be terrifying. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle a non-rewritten Url with the siteUrls.config rewriting rules.

This is because the querystring is stripped from the path before it is passed to the rules engine that processes each regex pattern.

In the UrlRewriteModule.cs, you'll find code that looks like this:

```
string strQueryString = "";
if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(app.Request.Url.Query)))
{
   strQueryString = request.QueryString.ToString();
   requestedPath = requestedPath.Replace(app.Request.Url.Query, "");
}
```

Then, further down the page, you'll find this:

```
//check for the existence of the LookFor value 
string pattern = "^" + RewriterUtils.ResolveUrl(app.Context.Request.ApplicationPath, rules[ruleIndex].LookFor) + "$";
Match objMatch = Regex.Match(requestedPath, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Thus you can fiddle with the regex you've posted until you go cross-eyed, but it will never work.  This is because the regex pattern is evaluated against the `requestedPath` value, which already has the querystring stripped from it.

You will need a rewriting solution that happens up-stream of the DNN Url Rewriter, or a customised version of the Url Rewriter (which I don't recommend).  Something like IIS7 Url Rewrite which gets to manipulate the Url before DNN even gets to see it.

But it's also a good time to pitch to whomever controls the code to stop using illegal Url characters, if that is, at all, a possibility.